# Is $D^n$ defined when $n = 0$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Define $D^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \le 1\}$.  Is $D^n$ defined when $n = 0$?  I would say no, since I don't think $\mathbb{R}^0$ is defined.

Comment: $\mathbb R^0$ *is* defined in most contexts: it is just the one point set. If you want, it is the underlying topological space of the real vector space of dimension zero.

Comment: Even if you look at $\mathbb R^n$ as the direct product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R^0$ should be the direct product of zero copies of $\mathbb R$, and that is in prettymuch every context defined to be a one-point set. This is a standard convention, and the only one which makes sense in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: I'd vote against closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using a definition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ like
$$\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid a_i\in\mathbb{R}\},$$
there would appear to be no definition of $\mathbb{R}^0$ (or it may even seem like $\mathbb{R}^0$ should be the empty set; but this would be terrible, since the rule $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\cong\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ would no longer be true).

For the purposes of generalization, the above definition is not ideal. A good definition to use is that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) (in an appropriate [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory)) of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$. $\color{red}{\textbf{The}}$ product of an empty collection of objects, when it exists, is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ [terminal object of the category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects); thus, thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as a topological space, we would say that $\mathbb{R}^0$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ topological space with a single point, while thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as an abelian group, we would say that $\mathbb{R}^0$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ trivial group.

You are thinking of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a normed real vector space (which is a special case of both of the above examples), and as a result, we would say that $\mathbb{R}^0$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ zero-dimensional real vector space (with its only possible norm), because such an object is terminal in the category of normed real vector spaces. Because the only element of $\mathbb{R}^0$ is its zero vector, we would therefore have that 
$$D^0=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^0:|x|\leq 1\}=\mathbb{R}^0.$$
Thus, $D^0$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ one-point topological space.

Why have I marked my uses of the word $\color{red}{\textbf{the}}$ this way? Because it really doesn't mean "the", in the sense you may be expecting. Really, any isomorphic object will do equally well, and there is no *single* thing to point to as being "the" product. For example, the one-point topological space
$$\{a\} \quad\text{with the topology}\quad\mathcal{T}=\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$$ is no better or worse than the one-point topological space
$$\{b\} \quad\text{with the topology}\quad\mathcal{T}=\{\varnothing,\{b\}\}$$
so which one should we say is $\mathbb{R}^0$? The correct action is *not to choose*.
[See this article on the nLab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/generalized+the).

Comment: I have never understood why so many people seem to object to the $0$-tuple $()$, which is a perfectly law-abiding citizen of the world!

Comment: (Pedantic complaint: there is no «the zero-dimensional real vector space». For example, the set $\{\text{Zev}\}$ is a possible zero dimensional real vector space)

Comment: @Mariano: I have marked all such uses of the word "the" in red :)

Comment: Good notation (and I am not saying coloring words is good notation :-) ) sometimes requires explanation :D